# Switching Battery to Usb

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, battery-operated

I am designing an hardware including MCU's, camera , RF components etc. Shematic looks fine and my question is actually about powering part. I have put some battery powered applications based LDO. It can handle 2.2V to 5.5V.
I want power my system when I plug USB too.
[image]

But If USB power lines is connected before Battery , then battery will go under tension with 5V. There must be a way to block battery when USB is on. how can I block battery without exceeding BOM file too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two Schottky diodes.
[image]

The load in the picture is 3.3 V net labelled point.

Comment: does USB plugging create ground loop? thanks for your answer by the way

Comment: ohh I see now. Okey now it became so clear :)